# Find a Weight Function with specific characteristics

Tags: functions, trigonometry, matlab

I need to build a weight function and I want to understand how you would do that. The reasoning you would use to define it.

My function has to be something like:

$f(\alpha)$ which is:

- $0$ if $\alpha>90^{\circ}$ and $\alpha<-90^{\circ}$.
- $1$ if $\alpha = 0^\circ$
- It has to arrive in $\pm 90^\circ$ with a tangent equal to $0$.

I was thinking to the function $f(\alpha)=1-\cos(\alpha)$ but it does NOT satisfy the constraint of the tangent

At the end I will implement this function in Matlab.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $\alpha>90^{\circ}$ and $\alpha<-90^{\circ}$?????

Comment: Yes why, is it strange?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(\alpha) = \left(1 - \left(\frac{\alpha}{90}\right)^2\right)^2$$

but

$$f(\alpha) = \left(\cos(\alpha)\right)^2$$ will work too

basically if $f(x_0)=0$, then $g=f^2$ will satistify $g(x_0)=0$ and $g'(x_0)=2f'(x_0)f(x_0)=0$

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer. Could you explain me how did you get to this result?

Thanks.